# Использование домена второго уровня для размещения нескольких сайтов

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Как будут восприниматься поисковиком несколько различных по назначению и дизайну сайтов, расположенных на одном домене?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будут воспринимать как один сайт. В том числе ТИЦ для них всех будет один. Если важна SEO, лучше такие штуки делать на поддоменах.

Адреса вида `site.ru/site1`,  `site.ru/site2`, лучше привести к виду `site1.site.ru` и `site2.site.ru`.

При этом, если у вас уже настроен первый вариант, можно настроить проксирующий nginx например, если вы планируете их добавлять в неограниченном количестве и не лазить для этого каждый раз в настройки DNS зоны.